# is it possible to make video to audio call using webrtc

Tags: javascript, webrtc

In my case user A is an admin and B is a client, A going to take seminar to B, so A should have constraint both audio and video is true, and B able to view A but B voice only enough to visible audible to A, so B should have constraint audio True and Video to false.

When I see this output, A able to audible B but B doesn't get Video of A.

So experts please let me know, is it possible to make video to audio call using WebRTC.

Agent:

```
function initiateCall() {
            prepareCall();
            navigator.getUserMedia({ "audio": true, "video": true }, function (stream) {
                localVideoStream = stream;
                localVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(localVideoStream);
                peerConn.addStream(localVideoStream);
                createAndSendOffer();

            }, function (error) { console.log(error); });
        };
```

Client

```
function answerCall() {
            prepareCall();
            navigator.getUserMedia({ "audio": true, "video": false }, function (stream) {
                localVideoStream = stream;
                localVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(localVideoStream);
                peerConn.addStream(localVideoStream);
                createAndSendAnswer();

            }, function (error) { console.log(error); });
        }
```

Comment: Have on mind security aspect , when someone allow video and audio on remote side - remote user can turn off/on in any time in call runtime.

Comment: Thanks Nikola Lukic, yes remote user can turn off/on in any time, but in my case always remote user not required to allow video(that means accessing cam), so is it possible to get permission only for audio??

Comment: Absolute yes , your code : { "audio": true, "video": false } is ok . Did you try to choose other devices at moment on allowing webcam with mic or only mic ? Sometimes default device is not proper device it is very usually .

Comment: There is the problem arise Nikola, when I set false to video in client window, this also blocked video streamed from admin(Admin could stream both video and audio but client should stream audio alone).

Comment: Hi Nikola, Updated my code snippet in question, please check

Comment: Show me code for stoping video on client , they must be something like this : LocalMediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;

Comment: Tried both  localVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;(stops videos sharing but camera light in ON state) and 
localVideoStream.getVideoTracks().forEach(function (track){track.stop();});(stopped entire stream).

Comment: what's wrong with "camera light in ON state" . I don't remember for light state but it is a possible .

Comment: In my case client have to stream audio alone, so my superiors questioning this "why camera is in On while streaming audio alone??"

Comment: The user must be notified of access to the microphone also. I think we've solved all the problems